# Unique Page views too low

Tags: google-analytics

I have a certain group of pages, i.e. `/projects/.+`, for which the unique page views are about factor 15 lower than their page views.

But it's really unlikely that our visitors view those pages 15 times in one session!

Something must be wrongly configured.

I checked the following:

- Pages don't get reloaded by scripts
- No page refers to itself
- Our domain also is not in the referrals

Also, the *previous path* for those pages is mainly the page itself, if viewed from the explorer-tab. If looking the navigation-tab, the numbers are completely different, but still bogus somehow.

I had events in mind, since event tracking is activated by means of Google Tag Manager, but for each event the *event without interaction* is set to true.

What can be wrong? Can it be the events?

Comment: Do I get it right that 15f events (with interaction) on those pages would result in exactly this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a misconfiguration in Google tag manager that I found with the help of [Margarita](http://www.ganotes.com/)

For any tag you could configure a tag that would be fired along with it.

We had the page view tag also fired when a click tag was fired.

Google changed the ui three times since we created that tag, and back then it seemed like a precondition for the tag.